# access waveform.png inside .css sheet to use webkit-mask?

Tags: webkit, soundcloud, waveform

based on the custom-player-examples im building my own player.
i used the minimal-player template.

after i set up the player like i want it to be, i started to customize the design (color.css, structure.css, standard,css)

but now i am stuck badly.. 
i found out that i cant change the background-color of the waveforms unless i use a webkit or the waveform.js.

the webkit should do just fine for me...

my only problem is, 
i dont know how to acess the track.waveform_url in neither my index.html or *.css files.

i know its inside waveform-container div but i need the url

```
  .wavekit{
    -webkit-mask-box-image: url(**IN HERE!!!**);
    background: #81D8D0;
    height: 280px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
  }
```

inside my stylesheet..

sadly i cant provide a link because its only on my hard drive yet

can somebody please help me out here?
thank you verymuch

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is very hacky, but after a couple of attempts I haven't found a better way to get waveform URL.

Idea is that for first play there is an event of `'ajaxSuccess'` that is firing and for the next ones there is `'scPlayer:onAudioReady'` event. The point being that image’s DOM is being generated by the plugin only at some point, so we need a certain “hook” like an event to know for sure the image will be already present in DOM.

```
$(document).bind('ajaxSuccess scPlayer:onAudioReady', function () {
    // get image from DOM of player 
    // it will be re-set every next play
    console.log($('.sc-waveform-container > img').attr('src'));
    $('.wavekit').style({
      '-webkit-mask-box-image': $('.sc-waveform-container > img').attr('src')
    });
});
```

Here's working example http://jsbin.com/uhofom/2/edit (only tested in Chrome)

Custom player project is outdated and will probably not get much attention. Its current state is not very extendable from the JavaScript point of view.

My suggestion would be to use something like [Audio5JS](http://zohararad.github.com/audio5js/) or [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) to play music and to have custom HTML and CSS UI. To get actual sounds or sets data you could query our HTTP API or use [SoundCloud JavaScript SDK](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript). Then you'd have proper object with all data including waveform API and would control the process much better.